# NoClassDefFoundError when running in linux

Tags: java, classpath

I am trying to run a simple java program in linux but getting a `NoClassDeffoundError`.

Basically, I have the following folder structure:

```
lib/myRef.jar
src/MyTest.java //there are classes that being referenced in myRef.jar
```

I compile like this:

```
javac -cp ../lib/myRef.jar MyTest.java //The class file is being gerenated in the same directory
```

Then when I try to run:

```
java -classpath . myRef
```

I am getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` on classes that I am referencing in the jar file.

Do I need to reference both *lib* and the current class that I am running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to also have *myRef.jar* on the classpath when running your code using java. Also, you seem to be passing the wrong classname to java, if you want to run your class `MyTest` as your main class, then use:

```
java -classpath ../lib/myRef.jar:. MyTest
```

Just *compiling* against the support classes that you use isn't enough, they'll also need to be in the classpath when you *run* your program.